# In echidna fuzzing, what is meant by *, r and *r?

Tags: solidity, echidna

In the echidna advanced documentation, it is mentioned as

> The label r on the left of each line indicates that Echidna can reach
> these lines, but they result in a revert.

however it doesn't describe in detail about what each of these statuses mentioned as below.

```
*   | 
r   |
*r  |
```